# Бот Телеграм должен отправлять текст из документа пользователю

Tags: python, telebot

Нужно, чтобы бот отправлял текст из документа какого-либо формата пользователю одним сообщением.
Библиотека: pyTelegramBotAPI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot("ВАШ_ТОКЕН")

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start', 'help'])
def send_welcome(message): # получаем от пользователя сообщение start или help
    with open("filename.txt", "rb") as f: # открываем документ
      contents = f.read().decode("UTF-8") # считываем все строки
      bot.reply_to(message, contents) # отправляем содержимое документа

bot.infinity_polling()
```

Comment: Не помогло,всё равно несколькими сообщениями кидает!

Comment: @Splake Добавьте, пожалуйста, в вопрос ваш код и результат его выполнения

Comment: @sigagleb Нашёл ошибку,спасибо